# Using strstr in C MBED, printing result

Tags: c++, c, strstr, mbed

I'm trying to compare two char arrays and print to the terminal whether or not the string was found.
When I run my code, the output printed returns a load of jibber that's not related to what I specified. I think more memory than I've specified is being printed but I'm not sure why.

Strstr returns a pointer to the beginning index of the found string (if found), null if not. I'm guessing this is what is causing the error - but I thought by only checking if the result was null rather than printing the result would bypass this.

My code:

```
include "mbed.h"
include "string.h"

char input[] = "Hello mbed";
char value[] = "llo";

int main() {

    char * output;

    output = strstr(input, value);

    bool found = false;

    if (output != NULL) {
        found = true;
    }

    printf(found ? "true" : "false");
}
```

My output:

trueloHello mbed½mà$Õ[F!FðMøDà(ÛÝéBÝ@\à0 ZFGñ@@Ñ. ZFGmºñªñ
ÝÜàøZFGm¸ñ¨ñôÜ[F!F«æ-+ -éðAF%FFÔà9F  °GmdùÕ(F½èð-éðAF%FFÈÕ0’à ‘ÕàAF8F°GmdùÕ(F½èðJh*Ð
hS`pHh@H`pGðµF°F2¡ü÷Èø(¿%0OÐWø%H±m-ùÓGà-IhB
`°ð½-?Ò x:(Ð!FhFþ÷ýhFþ÷mý(3ÐhFþ÷mý(hF Ðþ÷Uý#àjF¡ Fü÷Åøàþ÷?ý³ð¿$Ð¿ð¿Dôtð¿DôdFhFþ÷UýF0h”Fh0FG(¿Gø%è°ð½Oðÿ0°ð½ð¿$ÛÑð¿   $$Õç:ttl  :%p(¼¿ pGJëPø.......

Comment: Seems like a bug in the compiler implementation... perhaps you could inspect the generated assembly code to see what is going on. Or contact your vendor.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  then fix the resulting messages from the compiler

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted that would cause this error.  Is the header file "mbed.h" doing anything screwy? Try getting rid of the `include "mbed.h"` line.

Comment: It's also possible that there's something wrong with the code you're running, that we can't see because the code you've posted is not the code you're running.  (I know the code you've posted is not the code you're running because `include "string.h"` doesn't compile.)

Comment: Are you running your code on an ARM processor, in an embedded environment, using 'mbed'?  Does it have nonstandard usage of `main()` or anything?

Answer (score 1):

here is a corrected code that cleanly compiles, and works as desired

Note the way the `printf()` parameters are being set

Note the corrected list of `#include` statements

```
//include "mbed.h"
#include <stdio.h>    // printf()
#include <string.h>   // strstr()
#include <stdbool.h>  // bool, true, false

char input[] = "Hello mbed";
char value[] = "llo";

int main( void )
{

    char * output = strstr(input, value);

    bool found = false;

    if (output)
    {
        found = true;
    }

    printf( "%s\n", ((found)? "true" : "false" ));
}
```

Comment: I took the posted code and modified it in more or less the same way, and it worked properly for me, too.  I think there must be something wrong with the original code or its environment that we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the compiler and how it works with const strings. Add the NULL character to the strings to see if it stops printing...

```
printf(found ? "true\0" : "false\0");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Still regurgitating nonsense though. 

I changed my code to read:
if (output) { ....

- in order to remove dependencies on the NULL symbol, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: I've never heard of a compiler misbehaving in this way.

Comment: I've not seen that before either. It might be worth raising it as a bug, they might fix it. It's certainly surprising behavior with a const string.

Answer (score 0):

printf() might be a macro on your compiler/library/IDE. Including the header file, ensures that it works as expected. Also, on embedded, main() should never return